# Show gridLine only for columns in QTableView

Tags: c++, qt, stylesheet, qtableview

In a `QTableView`, irrespective if there are entries or not. I want to **show grid** to it (considering its fixed size `QTableView`), **but only for columns**, not for rows.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to overwrite the `paintEvent()` method, in addition to setting the `setShowGrid()` to false.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QStandardItemModel>
#include <QTableView>
#include <QHeaderView>
#include <QPaintEvent>

class TableView: public QTableView{
public:
    using QTableView::QTableView;
protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event){
        QTableView::paintEvent(event);
        if (horizontalHeader()->count() == 0 || verticalHeader()->count() == 0)
            return;
        QPainter painter(viewport());
        QStyleOptionViewItem option;
        option.init(this);
        const int gridHint = style()->styleHint(QStyle::SH_Table_GridLineColor, &option, this);
        const QColor gridColor = static_cast<QRgb>(gridHint);
        const QPen gridPen = QPen(gridColor, 0, gridStyle());
        painter.setPen(gridPen);
        int w = horizontalHeader()->offset();
        for(int i=0; i<horizontalHeader()->count(); ++i){
            w += horizontalHeader()->sectionSize(i);
            painter.drawLine(w-1, 0, w-1,viewport()->height());
        }
    }
};


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    TableView view;
    QStandardItemModel model(5, 5);
    for(int i=0; i< model.rowCount(); ++i)
        for(int j=0; j < model.columnCount(); ++j)
            model.setItem(i, j, new QStandardItem(QString("%1-%2").arg(i).arg(j)));
    view.setModel(&model);
    view.setShowGrid(false);
    view.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

[image]